# How to compare values from previous row for % difference

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, indexing, compare

Solving with Pandas

I have this dataset
this is the question:
For a user selected type of public transport type, display the year and the average trip distance in which the average has declined by at least 5% over the previous year.

```
     Year  MRT  LRT  Bus  Taxi

0   2004  11.5  0.0  5.2   8.5
1   2005  11.5  0.0  5.4   8.8
2   2006  11.3  0.0  5.3   9.1
3   2007  11.2  0.0  5.3   9.7
4   2008  11.2  2.1  5.3   9.0
5   2009  10.8  2.1  5.1   9.0
6   2010  10.3  2.1  4.8   9.3
7   2011  10.0  2.0  4.5   9.6
8   2012   9.6  1.0  4.4   9.7
9   2013   9.5  2.0  4.3   9.8
10  2014   9.2  2.0  4.3  10.0
```

eg. If i choose "Bus":
For easier visualization of that data column:

```
    Year  Bus
0   2004  5.2
1   2005  5.4
2   2006  5.3
3   2007  5.3
4   2008  5.3
5   2009  5.1
6   2010  4.8
7   2011  4.5
8   2012  4.4
9   2013  4.3
10  2014  4.3
```

it will compare 2005 data vs 2004 data if it has decreased more than 5%, if yes print it out, if no, carry on scanning.

**expected output:**
"In Year 2010, data is 4.8 and has declined more than 5% compared to the
previous year"
(note: 5.1 * 0.95 = 4.85)

"In year 2011, data is 4.5 and has declined more than 5% compared to its previous year"
(note: 4.8 * 0.95 = 4.56)

I was thinking of a for loop but I'm not really sure about how to use to it compare for 5% decrement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a column (per transport way) taking the value of your condition:

```py
df['hasDecreasedMarkedly'] = (df['Bus'] - df['Bus'].shift(1))/df['Bus'] >= 0.05
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas .pct_change().

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Year': {0: 2004,
  1: 2005,
  2: 2006,
  3: 2007,
  4: 2008,
  5: 2009,
  6: 2010,
  7: 2011,
  8: 2012,
  9: 2013,
  10: 2014},
 'Bus': {0: 5.2,
  1: 5.4,
  2: 5.3,
  3: 5.3,
  4: 5.3,
  5: 5.1,
  6: 4.8,
  7: 4.5,
  8: 4.4,
  9: 4.3,
  10: 4.3}})

df['pct_change']= df['Bus'].pct_change()

df['5 pct change'] = df['pct_change'] < -0.05
```

Output:

```
Year        Bus    pct_change       5 pct change
0   2004    5.2    NaN              False
1   2005    5.4    0.038462         False
2   2006    5.3   -0.018519         False
3   2007    5.3    0.000000         False
4   2008    5.3    0.000000         False
5   2009    5.1   -0.037736         False
6   2010    4.8   -0.058824         True
7   2011    4.5   -0.062500         True
8   2012    4.4   -0.022222         False
9   2013    4.3   -0.022727         False
10  2014    4.3    0.000000         False
```

To print out your request, "if it has decreased more than 5%, if yes print it out, if no, carry on scanning" you can do this.

```
(print(df.loc[df['5 pct change'] == True]))
```

Which prints this:

```
   Year  Bus    pct_change        5 pct change
6  2010  4.8   -0.058824          True
7  2011  4.5   -0.062500          True
```